# How to store a number above 50 digits as a string in java?

Tags: java

My assignment question:- A textbook has maximum 999 pages. Suppose you take first page as 1 and last page as 999, then you have to store the numbers from 1 to 999(including 1 and 999) as a single number[for example, first page is 5 and last page is 13 then the number to be stored is 5678910111213]. Also we have to count the occurrence of number which occurs maximum times(i.e., in above example 1 repeats 5 times, so frequency of 1 is 5) and then print the number and its occurrence.

The main problem is storing of number. If i take first and last number 5 and 9 respectively then my program works but 5 to 13 doesn't work(doesn't give the number i expect).

Comment: Why would you use a String?

Comment: You should post your current code along with this question, othwerwise we can only speculate why you get results other than what you expected.

Comment: Strings can hold up to around 2 billion characters.  Show us code or we can't help you.

Answer (score 0):

For this use a String:

```
String pages="";
for(int i=1;i<=999;i++)
{
      pages=pages+i;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The bigdecimal class stores numbers as strings.
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html

Although i don't think this is what you're looking for. What the question is asking for is to count the frequency of digits 1-9 when you have a string containing all numbers from 1 to 999(or some arbitrary range). The easy way would be to generate the string in a for loop

for (i=1 to 999)
 a += i

then iterate through the string checking what digit you have and add it to a counter. since you have 10 digits you can have a simple array counter that acts as a map.

counter[0]++ if digit is 0 etc.

Answer (score 0):

to make such a `String`

```
String pagestring = "";
for(int i=1;i<=999;i++){pagestring+=i;}
```

then make a `char[]`

```
char[] pagechar = pagestring.toCharArray();
```

count the numbers and find the max

```
for(char x:pagechar){
switch(x){
case "0": counter[0]++;
...
}}
for(int y:counter){
int a = 0;if(y>a)y=a;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this may help --

```
public Map<Integer, Integer> getFrequencies(int start, int end) {
    String num = "";
    for (int i = start; i < end + 1; i++)
        num += i;

    Map<Integer, Integer> frequencies = new HashMap<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < num.length(); i++) {
        int digit = Character.getNumericValue(num.charAt(i));
        Integer frequency = frequencies.get(digit);
        frequencies.put(digit, (frequency != null) ? ++frequency : 1);
    }
    return frequencies;
}
```

Also, in order to create a very large number you should use `BigDecimal`. So building on the above example, you can convert the `String` into a large number like this:

```
String num = "";
for (int i = start; i < end + 1; i++)
    num += i;

return new BigDecial(num);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use string to concatenate all numbers and rely on Collections.frequency method to find the max occurring digit. When I say digit I mean single digit. i.e.. a 11 will be treated as two 1s

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;


public class Pages {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int START = 5, END = 13;
        StringBuilder numbers = new StringBuilder();
        for(int i=START; i<=END; i++){
            numbers.append(i);
        }
        List<String> digits = Arrays.asList(numbers.toString().split("(?<=\\G.{1})"));
        String maxOccuring = "";
        int max = 0;
        for(int i=0; i<10; i++){
            int frequency = Collections.frequency(digits, "" + i);
            if(frequency > max) {
                max = frequency;
                maxOccuring = "" + i;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Number : " + numbers);
        System.out.println("Max occuring didgit : " + maxOccuring);
    }

}
```

Comment: can you explain me the working of 11th line "List<String> digits = Arrays.asList(numbers.toString().split("(?<=\\G.{1})"))"?

Comment: Its making a List which each character in the string. The syntax "(?<=\\G.{1})" is a regular expression that matches any character of length <= 1. So the split method will split our string to each character and form an array of string. `Arrays.asList` will convert this string array to list.